# Blazor pass to generic type to base class

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the base class `ListPage` as follows

```
@inherits TPL.Client.Core.Bases.Page 

@code {

[Inject] protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = null!;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    //stuff
}

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{       
   //stuff
}
```

}

and then the inheriting class `Organizations` as follows

```
@inherits TPL.Client.Core.Bases.ListPage

@layout TPL.Client.Shared.Layouts.ListPage

@page "/app/organizations"

<PageTitle>Organization</PageTitle>

@if (items != null)
{
    //stuff
}


@code {
    List<Domain.Organization.Organization> items;

    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync() 
    {
        base.OnParametersSetAsync();

       //stuff
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to move `List<Domain.Organization.Organization> items;` to the parent class (`ListPage`), make it `List<TItem> items` and then pass the generic type from the child class (`Organizations`).

Is that's something that's possible?

Comment: I think you're just looking for how to do generics in `.razor` files, and the answer is to use `@typeparam`.  The [docs on templated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0) covers this, but it can be used more broadly than that.

Comment: I don't think it's quite this. The docs are showing how to do generics down the chain, to a child component, and I am trying to figure out how to pass the generic type UP, to the base class.

Comment: You mean, `@inherits GenericBaseClass<Domain.Organization.Organization>`?

Comment: Yep. I could have sworn I tried that. Is that supposed to work?

Comment: I just tested that, and it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Something else may have borked my previous attempt. Thank you, add it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped.  I've provided an answer so you can close the loop on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a base class razor file such as:

```
@typeparam T

@code {
    public List<T> list = new();
}
```

You can subclass this by using `@inherits` with the type arguments:

```
@inherits GenericBaseClass<Domain.Organization.Organization>
```